# Auto Complete Place Api Android

Tags: android, api, google-places-api

I am developing android app i want to make auto Complete EditText so that the user can choose his city and address at first i use google place Api 
but that wasn't help at all because I can't change the language of the result 
any other Api I can use

Comment: of course you can change the language result, there is a param to do it. Check the documentation. 
I don't know better api for autocomplete of places right now.

Comment: I use AutoComplatePlace where the result depend on the system language,if you know any tutorial could help ,pleas tell me

Answer (score 0):

A Place Autocomplete request is an HTTP URL of the following form:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/output?parameters
```

to query for a specific language just add language parameter :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vict&types=geocode&language=fr&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

language codes are here 
https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport

Comment: pleas, if you know any tutorial that help me use that to implement as auto complete Edit text without using the AutoCompletePlace post it

Comment: autocomplete Android sdk. Please start looking for documentation